# best way to get the latitude and longitude values of a zip code - C#

Tags: c#, google-maps, latitude-longitude

What is the best way to get the latitude and longitude values of a zip code?

This is the function that I am currently using, but it only allows 2400 requests per 24 hours.

```
private Coordinates GetZipCoordinates(string zip)
    {
        string address = "";
        address = "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/xml?components=postal_code:" + zip.Trim() + "&sensor=false";

        var result = new System.Net.WebClient().DownloadString(address);
        XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
        doc.LoadXml(result);
        XmlNodeList parentNode = doc.GetElementsByTagName("location");
        var lat = "";
        var lng = "";
        foreach (XmlNode childrenNode in parentNode)
        {
        lat = childrenNode.SelectSingleNode("lat").InnerText;
        lng = childrenNode.SelectSingleNode("lng").InnerText;
        }

        return new Coordinates(Convert.ToDouble(lat), Convert.ToDouble(lng));
    }
```

Is there a better way to do it? I would like to avoid the request limit. Please suggest. Thanks.

Comment: How are you using these coordinates?  You might be able to brainstorm a way to need them less often, or cache them locally.

Comment: will be passing them in a querystring to make an api call... thank you Thomas and maniak1982

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can download a free zipcode database here:

http://federalgovernmentzipcodes.us/

Use your own and you don't have to make any remote calls.

Comment: Done. new to this site, so didn't know.

Comment: the above database says it was last updated 3 years ago. If you need something current https://softwaretools.com has a free non-commercial version that is kept up-to-date. hope it helps.  -- disclosure: I sometimes work for softwaretools

Comment: Thanks for that update @puddleglum Question: How often does the zipcode data actually change?  Is 3 years wildly out of date or mostly still very accurate?

Comment: @Lance - I mostly work in dev so I asked someone in our data area. Here is a summary of his response: "There are a few hundred changes per year (includes new zip codes, name changes, adding new cities per ZIP, and deletions). Sometimes there are county-wide changes that create a large number of updates at once. The changes can occur anytime but the July month is often the heaviest."  So, to your question - it sounds like it's not wildly out of date.   It would become quickly noticeable for something like address completion with a large customer base but tolerable for some situations.

Comment: Thank you.  That is good information which will come in handy for other reading this thread later.

Answer (score 1):

@Lance - That is the question of the day, "How often does zipcode data actually change?"  First, remember that a zipcode does not respect any political boundaries (they can span counties and states) because a zipcode is merely a delivery area, designed for the convenience of the US Postal Service and zipcodes change at the whim of the USPS.  Any time they want to realign boundaries or merge one zipcode into another (or any other change to a delivery area) will be a change to the zipcode data.  Creation or retirement of a zipcode (happens every month) will also mean a change to the data.

So, depending on your data needs, you may want to have data that is updated monthly.  Here is the data from [Aug2015](https://www.dropbox.com/s/o0gdz8b8xu2b7h9/zips-aug2015.txt.zip?dl=0).

If you need an API for zipcodes, here are a few:

- zippopotam.us
- smartystreets.com (I work here)
- zipcodeapi.com
- zipfeeder.us