# calculate the distance between two cities

Tags: c#, sql, .net

I have a bit of what I think is an odd request.  What I need to do is calculate the distance between the two cities, given their city/state/zip input data.  This would be as the crow flies, rather than mileage via highways and such.  And I would need miles output, i.e. x mile radius, in USA miles.

Again, I have city/state/zip input.  Most solutions I have located are via latitude/longitude instead.  Absent a city/state/zip solution, might there be a utility of some sort to convert city/state/zip input data to latitude/longitude and calculate based off of that?

Looking to incorporate this functionality into a .NET C#, MS SQL Server application.

Thanks in advance for any insight.

Comment: You're looking for a geocoding API.

Comment: @SLaks He doesn't need a full geocoding API.  there's free stuff out there that will give him conversion from zip to lat/long.  The lat/long is most likely the centroid of the zip code which depending on population could be huge or small.  and not very accurate

Comment: also large cities may have multiple zip codes which will affect the calculation

Comment: Two cities, or two zip codes? They are not the same thing.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [best way to get the latitude and longitude values of a zip code - C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30620666/best-way-to-get-the-latitude-and-longitude-values-of-a-zip-code-c-sharp)

Comment: Once you have the latiftude and longitude, you can use the Haversine formula to calcluate the distance.

Answer (score 2):

You will need to convert your address or partial address into valid latitude and longitude. There are several web services/APIs which can do this for you. Google has an API for this: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/start?csw=1

You will then need to do some math to calculate the distance, something like the [Haversine formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haversine_formula). If you google C# Haversine formula you'll find several articles, including some Stackoverflow questions about how to implement this.